# Is there a way to get a IGUIElement * given a pair of screen coordinates in Irrlicht?

Tags: user-interface, cursor, bounds, irrlicht

I have a pair of screen coordinates and I need to know if they overlap any GUI elements.

Is there some way of doing this or at least finding out if a given point is within the bounds of a GUI element?

It would be preferable if there was some sort of *`isPointInsideAnyGUIElements()`* function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`env->getElementFromPoint(position)`](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/docu/classirr_1_1gui_1_1_i_g_u_i_element.html#ae49f8a5228ce0c18e0c98becf74ee56a)

Comment: @George, asking questions here's not such a good idea. I recommend Irrlicht's Beginner's Help forum (we have a great community) or the chat room (#irrlicht on Freenode)

Comment: Thanks. I've been to the Freenode channel a few times and got some good help there. The idea of posting them here is that others will find this question when searching for it if they run into the same problem.